# Proving perpendicularity

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Let $I$ be its inscribed circles' center. Let $D$ be the intersection point of lines $AI$ and $BC$. The perpendicular bisector of $AD$ intersects with $BI$ in $E$.

Thesis:
$$
ED\perp CI
$$

How to prove that using synthetic euclidean geometry?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to show that $A,B,D,E$ are cyclic. To show this let the angle bisector of $\angle B$ cut the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$ at $E^{'}$. Then, since $\angle ABE^{'}=\angle DBE^{'}$, we have $AE^{'}=DE^{'}$. Therefore the perpendicular bisector of $AD$ passes through $E^{'}$. Hence $E^{'}$ is the same as $E$, that is $A,B,D,E$ are cyclic as we desired.
The remaining part is trivial.

Let $P$ be the intersection of $DE$ and $CI$ and $F$ the midpoint of $AD$. 
Using the cyclicity we've just proven, 
$$\angle AED=\pi-\angle ABD=2(\angle DAC+\angle ICA)$$
Because$ \triangle AED$ is isosceles, it's obvious that $\square PEFI$ is cyclic and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Please take a look on the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321816/proving-lines-are-perpendicular